# Basic shell implementation

Tags: c, linux, shell

Here is a small project to implement a basic shell. It is a personal ongoing project to keep system call usage fresh. It currently does background processes and some basic signal handling.

I am actually looking for code feedback in regards to professionalism. I want to know if my code is clear and easy to understand. I know my main function is currently doing too much and that I will handle in the short future.

```
/*
Description: This is a light implementation of a Linux shell
*/

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_LEN 4096
#define MAX_ARGS 256


struct proc_st {
    int bg;
    int exec;
    int commc;
    int fd_out;
    int fd_in;
    pid_t pid;
    char pbuff[MAX_LEN];
    char *commv[];
};


/* function prototypes */
void error_msg(char *);
void sig_handler(int);
void comm_identi(struct proc_st *, char *);

int main()
{
    struct proc_st *proc;
    char buff[MAX_LEN];
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    /* initialize signal handlers */
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_handler);

    printf("[SHELL]> ");
    for (;;) {

        while (fgets(buff, MAX_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {

            proc = malloc(sizeof(struct proc_st) + MAX_ARGS);

            /*initialize to zero */
            memset(proc, 0, sizeof(struct proc_st));
            proc->exec = 1;
            comm_identi(proc, buff);

            if (proc->exec == 1) {
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0 ) {
                    printf("fork error");
                } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
                    if (execvp(*(proc->commv), 
                        proc->commv) < 0 )
                        error_msg("could not execute");
                    free(proc);
                }

                /* parent */
                if (proc->bg == 0) {
                    if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) 
                            < 0)
                        error_msg("waitpid error");
                } else
                    printf("PID %d %s\n", pid, proc->pbuff);
            }
            free(proc);
            printf("[SHELL]> ");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}



void sig_handler(int signal)
{
    pid_t pid;

    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)) > 0) {
        printf("Child Process [%d]: Terminated", (int)pid);
    }
    if (errno != ECHILD)
        error_msg("waitpid() error");
}

void error_msg(char * msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
}


void comm_identi(struct proc_st *proc, char *buffer)
{
    char *tmp;

    /* replace newline with null */
    if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
    strncpy(proc->pbuff,buffer,MAX_LEN);

    tmp = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        proc->commv[(proc->commc)++] = tmp;
        tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    proc->commv[proc->commc] = NULL;

    /* check for built-in functions */
    if (proc->commc >= 1) {
        if(!strcmp(proc->commv[0], "exit")) {
            free(proc);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        if(!strcmp(proc->commv[0], "cd")) {
            proc->exec = 0;
            if (chdir(proc->commv[1]) != 0)
                error_msg("chdir() error");
        }

        /* check if it is a background process */
        if (*proc->commv[(proc->commc) - 1] == '&') {
            proc->bg = 1;
            proc->commv[(proc->commc) - 1] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

This code and updates are available in the [github repo](https://github.com/jarrocha/basic_shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Allocation and freeing

In the `while` loop of your infinite loop, you are allocating memory for `proc` only to be completely freeing it by the end of the loop. Why? Considering every loop you reset with `memset`, why not keep the same allocated memory for the entire time?

Your code would be much faster if you moved the allocation of `proc` out of both loops, and if you did not `free` the memory every iteration, too. Also, you seem to be `free`ing `proc` in a few other places in the loop; see if you can remove those, too.

---

### Refactor built-in functions

Here you are checking for commands that require special attention:

> ```
> if(!strcmp(proc->commv[0], "exit")) {
>     free(proc);
>     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
> }
>
> if(!strcmp(proc->commv[0], "cd")) {
>     proc->exec = 0;
>     if (chdir(proc->commv[1]) != 0)
>         error_msg("chdir() error");
> }
> ```

What if you need to add another command to this list for whatever reason? Now, you could just add another `if`, but then your code starts to look a little  more messy.

To make your code more flexible here, you could try splitting these built-in functions into a struct which stores the name of the built-in function and a pointer to a function to execute if this is come across.

Then, you could create a function that checks if the command entered is a built-in function. If it is, then the function can easily handle the situation using the built-in function's struct.

Here is a short snippet of what I mean:

```
struct builtin {
    char *name;
    function pointer;
} builtins = {
    "exit", builtin_exit,
    ...
};
```

Then, all you need is a function to check through `builtins` to see if the command entered is a built-in function.

From there, if you ever need to add another built-in function, you simply add another one to the array (and create its respective function), and you don't even have to touch the shell's main code.

---

### Exit number

In your `error_msg` function, you have this:

> ```
> exit(0);
> ```

Well, that doesn't make much sense; if there's an error, the code needs to return a non-zero number to indicate failure. Other than that, the environment in which this program was run will not be able to tell that there was an error.

---

### `const int` or `#define`

> ```
> #define MAX_LEN 4096
> #define MAX_ARGS 256
> ```

It would be better to use a `const int` here because that will actually define a type for the variable, where `#define` simply sticks that literal string after the macro name into the code and leaves it up to the compiler to determine a type for it.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your feedback and will edit the code and post it.

Comment: @jarr Okay, just make sure not to do that in the same post.

Comment: I have seen some posts where people re-edit to add new updates. I guess that's against the rules?  So the usual way is to keep the post as it is, keeping the suggestion to yourself or create a new one with the updates, right?

Comment: @jarr Right you are! Thanks for checking the rules, first! :)

Comment: Question. Point 1, I was like "that completely makes sense", if I am just using one struct at a time and want to stick with it, then just allocate once and memset to zero for the iterations. When I was writing this I was thinking of making this struct as a node which will be part of a job linked list. But point taken. Point 2, taken. Very creative and simple. Point 3, you're right, do "EXIT_FAILURE"?. Point 4, would adding a "static" would also make it better?

Comment: @jarr Yup, `EXIT_FAILURE` would work there. And, about `static`, you could put it there, but I don't think it's completely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

- Calling `prinf` from signal handler is unsafe (see `man 7 signal`).
- `comm_identi` parses the command line *and sometimes* executes the command. It is clear violation of a single responsibility principle. Leave the command execution logic to the main loop.
- The purpose of the surrounding `for(;;)` loop seems to keep the shell going after `fgets()` returns `NULL`. Since there is no attempt to recover (and some conditions, like hitting `EOF` are not recoverable at all), once `NULL` is returned the shell ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your feedback and will edit the code and post it.

Comment: vnp, I have a question. Point 1, taken but what about the errno variable? Is it still common in practice to save the value before and after a signal handler? Also Point 3, is it about the program ignoring SIGINT and SIGQUIT?

Comment: vnp, what about the call to error_msg() from the signal handler? I guess that one is also unsafe right?

Comment: @jarr Since it calls `printf` it is automatically unsafe. Re `errno` I suppose you should - if the handler is prone to change it.